# Why does OracleStatement.wasNullValue throw NullPointerException?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I do a simple query from Oracle database and I see this error in my log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.wasNullValue(OracleStatement.java:3337)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.wasNull(OracleResultSetImpl.java:122)
```

Here is the code that leads to that error:

```
public static Long getLong(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException{
        long val = rs.getLong(columnName);
        return rs.wasNull() ? null : val;
    }
```

Why wasNullValue throws NullPointerException? Is that the correct way to retrieve data from a result set?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Are you using a recent version of the driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an old bug in the Oracle JDBC thin driver where wasNull would throw an NPE if called on a closed ResultSet. So you might want to try to call rs.isClosed() before calling wasNull().

Comment: I updated to the latest driver and I don't see this error any more. Thanks!